# Приоритет regex перед сторонними библиотеками

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени, уважаемые! Меня интересует актуальность регулярных выражений в современном программировании. А именно - чему отдавать предпочтение? Писать самостоятельно шаблоны? Или использовать для этих целей специализированные библиотеки? Последние, если не ошибаюсь, не требуют знаний в области regex *(regular expressions)* ... И как быть, если к примеру мне куда проще работать именно с regex, а не изучать сторонние библиотеки для поиска решений, которые я могу решать и без этих библиотек? И последнее - если большинство мнений склоняется в сторону сторонних библиотек, то не означает ли это банальное не желание изучать regex?
Спс, ув.

Comment: Пишите как вам удобней.

Comment: какой-то поток сознания. Что за сторонние библиотеки вы имеете в виду, и как они заменяют регулярки?

Comment: @rjhdby, например Simple HTML DOM

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сравнивать теплое с мягким. Регулярные выражения - это "формальный язык поиска и осуществления манипуляций с подстроками в тексте" (вики), а HTML DOM - это HTML DOM. Единственное, что их объединяет - это то, что и там и там используются буквы/цифры и прочие символы

Comment: @rjhdby, не буду спорить, возможно я не верно привёл пример... Однако даже здесь, на SO, когда даёшь ответы на вопросы по регуляркам, то ответы "не приветствуются", если они написаны без использования Simple HTML DOM или подобной библиотеки.

Comment: Simple HTML DOM довольно кривая штука.

Comment: @Visman а чем вы пользуетесь?

Comment: Тут не приветствуется мода пихать регулярки везде, где только можно и где нельзя. В частности для разбора HTML страницы (которая является "не совсем правильным" XML) пользоваться регулярками - дурацкая идея. Это все равно, что накачивать шину от белаза велосипедным насосом, когда есть компрессор

Comment: @rjhdby теперь мне становится понятно. Использовать regex нужно для обычных строк, а для HTML-тегов соответствующие библиотеки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо понимать, что всякий инструмент предназначен для решения определенных задач. Для разбора XML существуют библиотеки, заточенные под разбор XML. Делающие это быстро, качественно и выдающие результат в удобном для дальнейшего использования виде. Для разбора JSON существуют json_encode/json_decode. Вы же в здравом уме не будете парсить json регулярками, собирая из него массив?

В принципе никто не запрещает парсить HTML с помощью регулярных выражений. Все зависит от конкретной задачи. Например если у вас есть переменная, содержащшая строку `<span>Дядя Вася</span>` и вам надо вытащить из нее "Дядя Вася", то, конечно, глупо прикручивать библиотеку обработки DOM, а гораздо проще воспользоваться регуляркой. А вот если у вас большой HTML-документ, в котором вам надо найти множество элементов по каким-то признакам, то регулярки станут вашей надгробной эпитафией.

Регулярные выражения - очень мощный инструмент, позволяющий решить множество проблем, однако кроме плюсов у них есть и минусы, о которых очарованные неофиты обычно не задумываются:

1. Первый минус. В некоторых условиях регулярные выражения могут работать [оооочень медленно](http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/10/16/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-.html).
   И такие случаи не предсказуемы.
2. Второй минус. Зачастую, решить задачу в несколько обычных команд бывает гораздо проще и быстрее, чем с помощью регулярок. Например вот вам регулярное выражение, которое всего лишь [валидирует email-адрес](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)
3. Третий минус. Сложность восприятия и понимания регулярки экспоненциально зависит от его длины. Вы можете понять, что делает регулярка из предыдущего пункта?
4. Четвертый минус прямо следует из третьего. Представьте, что вы написали что-то подобное, а через пол года понадобилось чуть-чуть изменить условия проверки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что вы посоветуете для разбора HTML-документов?

Comment: я использовал Simple HTML, нареканий особых не было.

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: @rjhdby, и у вас нет проблем с Simple HTML DOM для получения элементов по двум и более классам, причем эти нужные классы в html прописаны у разных элементов в разном порядке и перемежаются другими классами? :)

Comment: @Visman а у меня не было подобных кейсов ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   В общем то он на то и Simple

Comment: @visman никто не мешает вам порекомендовать вариант получше. Надеюсь это будут не регулярки ;)

Comment: Регулярки рулят :Р

Comment: @Visman я пока тоже склонен к этому мнению, но объективно оценить превосходство regex над другими библиотеками ещё не могу, т.к. не изучал их на таком уровне, как регулярки.

Comment: @Эдуард добавил немного в ответ

Comment: @rjhdby спасибо за ответ. __Вы можете понять, что делает регулярка из предыдущего пункта?__ Именно этот шаблон идеально подобран для демонстрации "как делать `не` нужно". Регулярные выражения, как и любой код, можно писать красиво, используя многострочное форматирование и комментарии прямо внутри шаблона. Для реализации такой возможности достаточно лишь использовать модификатор "x" в конце шаблона. А вот почему шаблон из этого примера был написан в одну строку, пока остаётся открытым.

Comment: @Эдуард я вас уверяю, если вы раскроете этот пример, отформатируете и добавите комментарии - понятнее он не станет :) С другой стороны, всю ту же валидацию можно сделать в несколько строк понятного кода. Этот пример очень доходчиво показывает, что всякой задаче потребен свой инструмент, и даже если ее можно сделать и на регулярках - это не значит, что такое решение будет лучшим :)

Comment: @rjhdby, в статье из первого минуса совершенно бредовый пример приведен, вот подтверждение https://regex101.com/r/Fiupjb/1 по скорости выполнения.

Comment: @Visman ничего, что в статье про java реализацию библиотеки, а вы про php? Суть проблемы в том, что скорость работы регулярок не предсказуема и при определенных входных данных можно получить сильную просадку производительности

Comment: @rjhdby, а взглянуть на теги у вопроса ;) Все у регулярок предсказуемо, если их правильно составлять.

Comment: @Visman поменяйте регулярку на `^(a*b*)*$` и удивитесь

Comment: @rjhdby, вы действительно думаете, что я буду использовать такую кривую регулярку?

Comment: @Visman мне без разницы, что будете или не будете использовать лично вы. Простое регулярное выражение на простых данных вводит PHP в коматоз? Вводит. Стало быть в "минусы" это внесено совершенно справедливо. На этом предлагаю закончить толочь воду в ступе.

Comment: @rjhdby, это не простая регулярка, а регулярка написанная человеком ни чего не понимающим в языке регулярных выражений. В ней масло масленое! Язык регулярных выражений надо знать как и любой другой язык программирования, если вы хотите его использовать. Вот и все!